# Angular 2 : dual list component with ordering

Tags: angular, npm-registry

Is  there any component  available in angular2 npm registry  with dual listbox component feature and  change order feature

angular-dual-listbox is available , but doesn't have option for reordering.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-dual-listbox

Sortable component is also available.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-sortable

But I want a combination of two

Comment: what about https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/picklist

Comment: Thank you. Looks promising. Is it compatible with bootstrap styles?

Comment: Nope it has its own styles but you can modify them easily